# Change view with navigation controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have a viewBased project and have two view "A" and "B" and put a button on view A and want to show view B when user push button.how can i show view B with navigation controler(means show with push)
I use below code but don't know what should i do before this code(means how to setup UINavigation controler,...)

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pop view B from the nav controller.

So when you press the button in view B just do this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Here is a tutorial on how to set up a nav controller with three views and buttons to change.
 [Navigation Controller Tutorial](http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-tutorial-navigation-controller.html)

Comment: when i touch button on view A doesn't show view B(means code doesn't work)

Comment: O sorry misunderstood you, are your views set up within a navigation controller?

Comment: I added a link to my post with a tutorial to set up a navigation controller and do exactly as what you are describing.